# How to check in assemblies in TFS source control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

When using custom assemblies in a visual studio project. How does one check in those assemblies in source control with the project so that anyone can download the project and build right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- Create a folder called something like *libraries*
- Put your custom assemblies in to that folder
- Make sure your references point to the assemblies in that folder

At that point you should be able to include that folder with those assemblies in your source control.

Comment: Mine is called "dependencies", but the idea is the same. I also include things that might not be in the GAC like Enterprise Library, etc.